# Twig extends short path

Tags: symfony, layout, twig

Imagine I have a bundle with this views structure:

```
 Ressources
   - Views 
     - Content 
       - layout.html.twig
       - view.html.twig
```

so the layout is in the same folder like the view

I know I can extend the layout by typing something like :

```
 {% extends "fooBarBundle:Content:layout.html.twig" %}
```

How would I just reference the current folder?

```
 {% extends "layout.html.twig" %}
```

It says it can't find it... I'm just asking if this is possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want a shorter syntax, simply move your `layout.html.twig` to `app/Resources/views` and call it `{% extends "::layout.html.twig" %}`

Comment: nice this is what i was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a shorter syntax, simply move your `layout.html.twig` to `app/Resources/views` and call it:

```
{% extends "::layout.html.twig" %}
```

Comment: i accepted this as answer, but if anyone knows how to select the current folder, post it